# Call method from Local inner class in inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have this code:

```
class A{
    class B{
        public void foo(){
            class C{
                public void bar(){
                    baz();
                }
            }
        }
        public void baz(){}
    }
    public void baz(){}
}
```

If i call baz() in C.bar(), it will call B.baz(). If i make a reference in A from this, (A aref = this;) then i can call A.baz() through it. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You may use `A.this.baz()`. `A.this` is called a *qualified this expression*.